# How to mantain informations between scene transition?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on temple run like game using this Kit. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3292. I want to insert a room with two doors , when my player enters in the room it stops running and user can control with arrow keys , and when it leaves the room by back door it starts running again . what should i do when it collides with the door collides ?
I am doing this by replacing the scenes. I am instantiating an empty Game-object prefab in GamePlayScene when player is colliding with that i am loading HouseScene and when it is colliding with back door (in HouseScene) i am loading GamePlayScene. but the game is starting from the beginning. how can I resume the game From where I left And keep the track of Distance covered and coins collected? And also for HouseScene . Remember the points i achieved in it. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Comment: @WaquasMajeed: I have edited your question's title. I think it's more self-explanatory, now, about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save the informations that you want to keep between your scenes.
You have some possibilities about that:

1) Save your informations in a text file and retrieve those when you load a new scene (but this way is a bit "dirty" and not recommended...the next points of this list are better solutions);

2) Using [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). They provide getters and setters to retrieve/store data in/from the registry of your operative system.

3) Using an object (as a container) that contains all your "global" variables (the ones that you want to mantain between scenes' transition), and invoking the [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) function on it. That way, your "container" (with its data) will persist in the entire life cycle of the game.