# Keeping Scores in Unity and pass to next scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After reading and trying many different examples, I am still stuck with this fairly simple problem on getting a score from one level to the next in Unity.

I have a C# script that handles my game logic for a level:

First, I set my level variables:

```
    public class GameLogic : MonoBehaviour {

public GUIText countText;
public GUIText targetCity;
public GUIText gameOverText;
public GUIText endScoreText;
public GUIText timerText;
public Texture2D bgImage;
private int count;
public GameObject cityPrefab;
List<MyCity> mycities;
public float finalScore; // I Want this value to be available when my next scene loads
private float startTime;
```

After this, my level code executes fine, until the GameOver condition is met (time is up). Then, this code executes:

```
    public void GameOver ()
{
    gameOverText.text = "time is up!";
    endScoreText.text = "You have found " + count.ToString() + " cities. Good wrok!";
    Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("EmptyCity"));
    Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("City"));
    Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("TargetCity"));
    finalScore = count; // SO AT THIS STAGE, MY FINAL SCORE IS SET AND READY TO BE PASSED TO THE NEXT SCENE. QUESTION IS HOW?




    StartCoroutine(Wait());

}



IEnumerator Wait() {

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
    Application.LoadLevel (3);
}
```

So, I end my level with an updated value in public float 'finalScore'. So far so good. Now my problem starts: Level 3 loads and all gameobjects from level 2 are destroyed. In my game, level 3 is a simple Unity scene where I congratulate the player on his performance. I want to have access to that public float finalScore from my previous scene (level2).

I know I have to use Dontdestroyonload somewhere. But I don't know how. How and where do I create a GameObject that has the public float 'finalScore' in it? How do I call that GameObject in my new level so that I can do something like this in my new level:

```
    public GUIText ContratsOnScore;

    void SetContratsText() {

    CongratsOnScore = "Congratulations, you scored" + (finalScoreFloatValue from Previous level).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DontDestroyOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method is callable on an *object*, not on a single variable. It represents the best possible approach for a value of that kind, that needs to be "exported" from your actual scene.

However, you can also use [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). They are intended for informations at a "higher" level of persistency, like flags for unlocked levels, final scores for a ranking system, or attributes of a customizable character. That's why the DontDestroyOnLoad way is better suited (for your "temporary" score), but you can use this one also. Basically, PlayerPrefs are information stored in the registry of your operative system.

Before exiting from the actual scene, save the score this way:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", finalScore);
```

And, when next scene starts, initialize score's variable by retrieving that information:

```
finalScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");
```

*([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393157/how-to-mantain-informations-between-scene-transition/21400450#21400450) a similar post)*

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. But, what if I create a separate empty GameObject and add it to my scene? I put this code on the GameObject:

        using UnityEngine;
        using System.Collections;

         public class LastLevelScore : MonoBehaviour {
        void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        }
        }

Then, how to I add the value of the public float finalSocre to that Gameobject? And secondly, how do I call that GameObject and its value in my new scene? (not sure why my code doesn't format in the comments)

Comment: The "empty" GameObject created this way must exihibit the score variable as an exposed one. Then, from your other objects, you could retrieve that variable from it through a `GetComponent()` call. I usually write in Unityscript, and I am not familiar with C#: that's why I can't give you a complete example, sorry...

Comment: Thanks Andrea. Drives me crazy that such a basic simple concept is in fact so complex in this case. I'll see what I can find on Unityscript instead.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved. :-) Yes, it could be "complex" at a first glance, but keep in mind that Unity gives you a set of possibilities for that purpose. You could also set up a plain text file and read values from it! The DontDestroyOnLoad and PlayerPrefs approaches are just smarter solutions, a "plus" of the engine. Good Luck for your learning phase!

Comment: Thanks man. I chose the player prefs route. Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Someone else said, and I shamelessly quote, use a static variable for your data in a C# class, and there you go...

(Still I'd prefer to pass parameters to LoadLevel itself, but that's another story)