# Unity3D - Keep Clouds Positions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been Googling many hours trying to keep the clouds' positions when reloading it's scene but still no luck.

Could you point out my mistakes in my code?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

 public Transform[] clouds;
 public float speed = 0.2f;

 void Update () {
     for(int i = 0; i < instance.clouds.Length; i++){
         if(instance.clouds[i].position.x >= 10f){
             instance.clouds[i].position = new Vector3(-10f, instance.clouds[i].position.y, 0);
         }
         Vector3 vec = instance.clouds[i].position;
         vec.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
         instance.clouds[i].position = vec;
     }
 }

 static MenuScript instance;

 void Awake(){
     if(instance == null){
         instance = this;
         DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
     }else{
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User PlayerPrefs to replace DontDestroyOnLoad:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("x", 10.0f);
```

To get the value back, use

```
PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("x");
```

> The PlayerPrefs stores and accesses player preferences between game sessions.

- On Mac OS X PlayerPrefs are stored in ~/Library/Preferences folder, in a file named unity.[company name].[product name].plist, where company and product names are the names set up in Project Settings. The same .plist file is used for both Projects run in the Editor and standalone players.
- On Windows, PlayerPrefs are stored in the registry under HKCU\Software[company name][product name] key, where company and product names are the names set up in Project Settings.
- On Linux, PlayerPrefs can be found in ~/.config/unity3d/[CompanyName]/[ProductName] again using the company and product names specified in the Project Settings.
- On Windows Store Apps, Player Prefs can be found in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages[ProductPackageId]>\LocalState\playerprefs.dat

Comment: This is a great option but I want to learn how `DontDestroyOnLoad` works. Thanks!

Comment: It is **not a good practice** using DontDestroyOnLoad, which has been discussed elsewhere.

Comment: why is using `DontDestroyOnLoad` not a good practice anymore?

Comment: You might search google to see why. for instance, using DontDestroy... you enforces tight coupling between scenes.

Comment: Good idea mate. Thanks

Comment: Similar discussions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862932/keeping-scores-in-unity-and-pass-to-next-scene)

Comment: PlayerPrefs values persist even after the game closes. This may or may not be what Jim is looking for. If you don't understand what dontdestroyonload does and think through the repercussions, you can end up with duplicated objects or other confusing scenarios so you should use it sparingly. It does have a purpose and if used properly is still useful imho.

Comment: This is not an excuse to avoid using PlayerPrefs. You can of cource use PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll() ; to remove them. Trivial and straightforward.

Comment: @PaulHansen,  "If you don't understand ..." I am curious what drives you think so? Mind explaining a little bit?

Comment: Didn't you see Delete **ALL** ? Did you read the docuementation of what DeleteAll() does?

Comment: As I said I'm trying to learn how `DontDestroyOnLoad` works. Yes I can use `PlayerPrefs` but I don't want to avoid using the former method

Comment: You can do it yourself with no problem at all. I never stop you doing so? I don't quite understand your logic, sorry about that.

Comment: @PaulHansen, it should be noted that good vs bad practice never stops you doing so, you can anyway use it at your own discretion. Though this discussion is bit off-topic.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that you personally didn't know how they worked. It is true that PlayerPrefs would work fine in most cases. A good use case for Dontdestroyonload is If you had hundreds of clouds that had to persist between level loads and they had other values stored on them that would need to be saved as well then you may run into the storage limit of 1MB for PlayerPrefs.

Comment: @PaulHansen, thanks Paul, but your discussion is bit off-topic. In case of hundreds of data entries, there are more than one elegant ways that are even better than Dontdestroyonload. But this is less pertinent, are you with me? :)

Comment: Well we don't know how many clouds are in his array and we don't know what else is stored on those clouds. So I felt like it was pertinent since it may effect how well this works for him.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how the cloud array is being populated. The MenuScript class may not be destroyed but the individual clouds may be being destroyed and re-loaded.

If all that needs saved is the position of the clouds you could make an array to store the positions for each cloud on the MenuScript to make sure those values are saved.

Comment: There are 5 clouds already in the scene. I just populated them in the `MenuScript` class.

How do I make it so the cloud arrays will not be destroyed as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to set each to not destroy on load.

Comment: This is the result I get: `The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.`

Comment: Honestly if I was to write and test the code for you in this case, I feel that you would not learn how it works and it could cause more issues for you down the line. I suggest looking at the line that error is happening on and try to think through why it would not be still loaded at that point.

Comment: It may be better to have a cloud class attached to each cloud and that would tell the cloud to move. You could then set them to don't destroy from there. Of course you would have to to have a way to make sure they don't spawn a second set when you re-load the scene so it might not work for what you are doing.

Comment: I didn't quite get your instruction. I'm beginning to think about using `PlayerPrefs` now. Thanks

Comment: No problem whatever works for you. I did update my answer again with a possibly simpler solution than my original idea.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm going to create a static array list for clouds positions right?

Comment: The reason why `PlayerPrefs` is not my thing is that some week ago I've read that using it is expensive than using `DontDestroyOnLoad` or singleton. Is this correct?

Comment: Playerprefs is likely slower since it writes to the disk but I'm not sure if the difference would be enough to notice.

Comment: Sine you already are using a singleton I don't think it actually matters if the array is static or not. I think it makes more sense for it not to be static but that's just how I think about it.

Comment: I think it would be a better option if I'm going to save a user's data which is only once in a while compare to what I'm trying to accomplish such as switching scenes. I'm now trying to edit my code to use static list.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a workaround for this issue:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MenuScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform[] clouds;
public float speed = 0.2f;

public static List<Vector3> cloudsPositions;

void Start(){
    if(cloudsPositions == null){
        cloudsPositions = new List<Vector3>();
        for(int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++){
            cloudsPositions.Add(clouds[i].transform.position);
        }
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++){
            clouds[i].position = cloudsPositions[i];
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateCloudsPositions(){
    cloudsPositions.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++){
        cloudsPositions.Add(clouds[i].transform.position);
    }
}

void Update () {
    for(int i = 0; i < clouds.Length; i++){
        if(clouds[i].position.x >= 10f){
            clouds[i].position = new Vector3(-10f, clouds[i].position.y, 0);
        }
        Vector3 vec = clouds[i].position;
        vec.x += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        clouds[i].position = vec;
    }
}
}
```

What I did was I stored the clouds' `position` to a static list so when the scene is reloaded, the script will update their positions on `Start` function.

Thanks to all who assisted me :)